# How to select the total number of logins by date?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table **user**

I need to select the total number of logins by date.

Comment: And where is the problem? This is straight forwards stuff ...

Comment: What query you tried so far?

Comment: This select is complicated for me because I need to use the variables like. The sql should be like: SELECT sum(loginCount) FROM user WHERE Date >= :startDate AND Date < :endDate (there is the option to choose the date), but as I do not have the Date column I do not know how to do this: year, month, day >= startDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by date and use `sum` to aggregate all users:

```
select year, month, day, sum(loginCount) 
  from user 
 group by year, month, day
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Day, Month, Year, SUM(LoginCount)
FROM User
GROUP BY Day, Month, Year
```

By grouping by the touple (Day, Month, Year) you are basically grouping by date. SUM(LoginCount) will sum all the values on LoginCount for the same touple you are grouping by.

Answer (score 0):

Create a date datatype using year, month and day.  Then select the sum of logins grouping by this date